# Can I copy the KeyStore .jks file to another computer without certificates?

Tags: java, certificate, keytool, jks

First, I copied the certificates in the right place. Then I used the keytool and added/imported the TrustedCertEntry and PrivateKeyEntry of these certificates into the **KeyStore .jks file**. Everything is fine and works as expected.

The question is, can I just **copy the .jks file** to another computer without the certificates?

Best regards,
Sherzad

Answer (score 2):

JKS is machine independent and can be transferred to different machines/servers